# How do I find the bases of the Jordan Canonical Form of $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $$C = \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
>    0 & -1 & -2 & 3 \\
>    0 & 0 & -2 & 3 \\
>    0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
>    0 & 0 & -1 & 2
>   \end{array} } \right].$$ What is the Jordan canonical form of C?

We know that the characteristic polynomial

$$\chi_C(\lambda) = (z - 1)^4$$

So the algebraic multiplicity of $1$ is $4$.

1. How do I find the geometric multiplicity of $1$?
2. If the geometric multiplicity of $1$ is less than $4$, how do I find the bases that give me the Jordan canonical form?

Comment: Geo-multi = $\dim (\mathrm {Ker} \,(C - 1I)) = n - \mathrm {rank} (C - 1I)$, hence you could find $\mathrm {rank} (C-1I)$ via RREF or some other thing.

Comment: $C$ is not invertible, so shouldn’t it’s characteristic polynomial be divisible by $z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow [this algorithm](https://math.rice.edu/~friedl/math355_fall04/Jordan.pdf) described by Stefan Friedl.

A little work shows that the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is
$$
\chi_C(t)
= t \cdot (t - 1)^{3}
$$
which gives a table of eigenvalues
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\lambda & \operatorname{am}_C(\lambda) & \operatorname{gm}_C(\lambda) \\ \hline
0 & 1 & ? \\
1 & 3 & ?
\end{array}
$$
Here, $\operatorname{am}_C(\lambda)$ is the *algebraic multiplicity* of $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $C$ and $\operatorname{gm}_C(\lambda)$ is the *geometric multiplicity*.

Our factorization of the characteristic polynomial allowed us to fill in the algebraic multiplicities in our table. The geometric multiplicities can be computed from the definition $\operatorname{gm}_C(\lambda)=\operatorname{nullity}(\lambda\cdot I-C)$. In our case, we have
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\lambda & \operatorname{am}_C(\lambda) & \operatorname{gm}_C(\lambda) \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 1
\end{array}
$$
Note that $\operatorname{gm_C}(0)$ can also be quickly inferred from the inequality $1\leq\operatorname{gm}_C(0)\leq\operatorname{am}_C(0)=1$.

At this stage, we can infer the Jordan form $J$ of $C$. Recall the interpretations of the multiplicities of the eigenvalues as
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{am}_C(\lambda) &= \text{number of $\lambda$'s on the diagonal of $J$} \\
\operatorname{gm}_C(\lambda) &= \text{size of the largest Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda$ inside $J$}
\end{align*}
In general, knowing these multiplicities is not enough to infer $J$. However, in our case we can see that 
$$
J=\left[\begin{array}{r|rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

Now, we proceed to compute the change of basis matrix $P$. The easiest way to start is to note that 
$$
E_0 = \operatorname{Span}\{\langle1, 0, 0, 0\rangle\}
$$
This gives our first column of $P$, so
$$
P=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & ? & ? & ? \\
0 & ? & ? & ? \\
0 & ? & ? & ? \\
0 & ? & ? & ?
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, to build the other three columns, we compute the numbers 
$$
d_k=\operatorname{nullity}((\lambda\cdot I-C)^k)-\operatorname{nullity}((\lambda\cdot I-C)^{k-1})
$$
for $1\leq k\leq\operatorname{gm}_C(\lambda)$ where $\lambda=1$. For us, these numbers turn out to be
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= 1 & d_2 &= 1 & d_3 &= 1
\end{align*}
We now take these numbers and build a diagram of empty boxes
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\Box\\ \Box\\ \Box
\end{array}
$$
The algorithm we're following demands that we start at the bottom of this diagram and fill the boxes in row $k$ with linearly independent vectors that belong to $\operatorname{Null}((\lambda\cdot I-C)^k)$ but *not* $\operatorname{Null}((\lambda\cdot I-C)^{k-1})$. Once a box in the diagram is filled with a vector $\vec{v}$, the box immediately above it is filled with $(\lambda\cdot I-C)\vec{v}$.

In our situation, we have
\begin{align*}
(I-C)^2 &= \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}\right] & (I-C)^3 &= \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
We easily see that $\langle0,1,0,0\rangle\in\operatorname{Null}((I-C)^3)$ but $\langle0,1,0,0\rangle\notin\operatorname{Null}((I-C)^2)$. This allows us to fill out our diagram
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\fbox{$\left\langle0,\,-1,\,-1,\,-1\right\rangle$}\\
\fbox{$\left\langle-1,\,-1,\,1,\,0\right\rangle$} \\
\fbox{$\left\langle0,\,1,\,0,\,0\right\rangle$}
\end{array}
$$
This defines our matrix $P$ as
$$
P = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
We can verify ourselves that this is indeed correct
$$
\overset{C}{\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & -1 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2
\end{array}\right]}
=
\overset{P}{\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{J}{\left[\begin{array}{r|rrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{P^{-1}}{\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -2
\end{array}\right]}
$$

Comment: "In general, knowing these multiplicities is not enough to infer ." What do we do in that case? I would greatly appreciate you if you could tell me.